# how to reduce the time to move pods on another nodes when a node is down

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a problem, I can't find how to change the pod check parameter to  move on another node. When k8s detects that a node is down .

I found the parameter `--sync-synchrionizes` but I'm not sure.

Someone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `kube-controller-manager.conf` and update the following parameters: (you can find the file in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`)

```
node-status-update-frequency: 10s
node-monitor-period: 5s
node-monitor-grace-period: 40s
pod-eviction-timeout: 30s
```

This is what happens when node dies or go into offline mode:

1. The kubelet posts its status to masters by `--node-status-update-fequency=10s`.
2. Node goes offline
3. kube-controller-manager is monitoring all the nodes by `--node-monitor-period=5s`
4. kube-controller-manager will see the node is unresponsive and has the grace period `--node-monitor-grace-period=40s` until it considers node unhealthy. PS: This parameter should be in N x node-status-update-fequency
5. Once the node marked unhealthy, the `kube-controller-manager` will remove the pods based on `--pod-eviction-timeout=5m`

Now, if you tweaked the parameter `pod-eviction-timeout` to say 30 seconds, it will still take total 70 seconds to evict the pod from node The node-status-update-fequency and node-monitor-grace-period time counts in node-monitor-grace-period also. You can tweak these variable as well to further lower down your total node eviction time.

Comment: If node down and not reachable , then will kube-controller-manager still able to remove pods?

Comment: Kube controller manager runs on the master node and hence it will be able to detect the any other node goes down. It will know that a particular node is unresponsive it will wait for a grace perios and if it still doesn;t come up. It will mark that node as unhealthy

Comment: unfortunathely if add the params that doesn't change the default time of kubernetes .

Comment: I have been using those settings from quite a time in my cluster and everything works fine.It takes 70 seconds to move pods to other node, by default it takes around ~6minutes. Could you please check that your kube-controller-manager docker container running with those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Once pod is scheduled to particular node, it is not moved or shifted to any other node in any case.New pod created on available node.

If you don't have deployment or RC, to manage state(number of pods) of your application, it will be lost forever. But if you are using deploy or other objects who is responsible to maintain desired state, then if node goes down, it detects the changes in current state and then it create new pod to another node(Depending on node capacity).

Comment: or I misspoke or you misunderstood the question.

when a nodes falls I don't want to wait 50s before the pod is moved to another node but 5s max .

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely agree with praful above. It is quite challenging to evict the pods from failed node and move them on to another available node in 5 seconds. Practically not possible. You need to monitor the node status, allow grace period to confirm that node in indeed down, then mark the status as unhealthy. Finally move the pods to other active node.
You can tweak those node monitor parameters to much less values but the downside is control pane performance would be hit as more connections are made between Kubelet and api server.
Suggest you run 2 replicas for each pod so that your app is still be available to serve the user requests